# Secure iPhone (iOS) /server communication

Tags: iphone, ios, security, rest

I'm building and iPhone App that will make requests to an application of mine running on a server. I'm using REST to build the server's application API. What is the best way for securing the requests from the iPhone to the server and viceversa.  Is OAuth a good option? What would you recommend?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If it's a server you control, use a SSL/TLS connection for all communications between the phone and your server.  Make sure that the phone app code checks the server's certificate (e.g., to check that it is a cert for your domain name, where your domain name is hardcoded into the source code).  This will protect against eavesdropping, man-in-the-middle attacks, message forgery, and other attacks on the data while it is in transit.

Answer (score 1):

There is not really any way to answer the question "what's best" without a lot more information on the security needs of your app.

In general, you should consider authentication, authorization, and transport.

Authentication could be as simple as username/password login. This could be simple authentication, OAuth, kerberos, etc. It is meant to identify the user. Authorization deals with which services are allowed to be accessed by which groups or individuals. You'd need a way to grant and maintain privileges. Finally, securing the transport typically means using encrypted services, such as HTTPS over SSL. This prevent data from being intercepted or altered during transport.

There are many other considerations to think about including how your protecting personally-identifiable information, encryption, etc., but again, there is no one-size-fits-all solution that could be recommended.